# create stacked column chart to show running time

Tags: excel, stacked-chart

I have data on 5 runners for 1 week; start time and end time in a race. I want to graph how long it took each runner to finish the race
when I subtract the cells for start and end time, I get a result as 3:00 AM instead of 3 hours. I think this is why I'm having an issue creating a stacked column chart

how can I subtract 2 timestamps and get it to spit out just the hours instead of another time stamp?

I want the date on x axis and time to complete the race on y axis

thank you

here is a sample of the data
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUf9Z.jpg

i want a stacked column chart that has dates on the x axis. so 1/1 will have 1 bar that has 30 mins for racer 1, 35mins for 2, and 40 mins for 3

Comment: This would be a lot easier to understand if you could provide some sample data and maybe the chart you currently have (you can upload screencaps to http://imgur.com and link to them)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.